# VB.Net Label visuals change from design to runtime

Tags: vb.net

I'm designing a little program in vb.net and have encountered some really strange behavior. I've got a clock that counts down when you click the button, so the text in the Label needs to be dynamically adjusted. The amount of time is based on some settings loaded in the game initialization so the label is updated with the appropriate start time when the form loads. However, as soon as I update the text in the label during runtime the spacing or sizing or something gets all messed up.

[Design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1g4G.png)

[Runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF0A9.png)

There is nothing in the code that is changing the font. This is only happening with the 5:00 minute label, the two smaller ones work fine. I've compared every property of the working labels with the janky one and they are the exact same.

Thoughts?

Comment: Looks as though the runtime one is attempting to show the mins with a leading zero, and this is pushing the right-hand seconds off the edge of the label. In which case, this is nothing to do with fonts, but instead is the formatting of the string in your code.

Comment: Wow. Yep. .ToString("mm\:ss") - I'm an idiot! Thank you!!